# Convert Current Date Time to Romania Time with Day Light Saving

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, dst, systemtime

I need some sample to convert current system date time to Romania Time Zone EET with day light saving. Can any one please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ZoneDateTime` like :

```
ZoneDateTime ett = ZoneDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Bucharest"));
```